# Treeview ajustado al tamaño de la ventana

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con una interfaz gráfica usando la librería tkinter.

Me gustaría ajustar el ancho de cada tabla al ancho de la ventana.

La forma que se me ocurre es modificando el valor del parámetro **width** de cada **self.tree.column** y **self.tree2.column** hasta que sumen el ancho deseado.

Mi pregunta es, hay alguna forma más sencilla de hacer que se ajusten al ancho de la ventana? Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3


class App:

    db_name = 'database.db'

    def __init__(self, window):

        self.win = window

        self.win.geometry('1024x768')

        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(selectmode='browse', height=10, columns=[f'#{n}' for n in range(1,8)])

        self.tree.config(show='headings')
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.tree.column('#1', width=100, anchor='c')
        self.tree.column('#2', width=200, anchor='c')
        self.tree.column('#3', width=100, anchor='c')
        self.tree.column('#4', width=150, anchor='c')
        self.tree.column('#5', width=100, anchor='c')
        self.tree.column('#6', width=100, anchor='c')
        self.tree.column('#7', width=100, anchor='c')

        self.tree.heading('#1', text='columna 1')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='columna 2')
        self.tree.heading('#3', text='columna 3')
        self.tree.heading('#4', text='columna 4')
        self.tree.heading('#5', text='columna 5')
        self.tree.heading('#6', text='columna 6')
        self.tree.heading('#7', text='columna 7')

        self.tree2 = ttk.Treeview(selectmode='browse', height=10, columns=[f'#{n}' for n in range(1,6)])

        self.tree2.config(show='headings')
        self.tree2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.tree2.column('#1', width=150, anchor='c')
        self.tree2.column('#2', width=250, anchor='c')
        self.tree2.column('#3', width=150, anchor='c')
        self.tree2.column('#4', width=100, anchor='c')
        self.tree2.column('#5', width=100, anchor='c')

        self.tree2.heading('#1', text='columna 1')
        self.tree2.heading('#2', text='columna 2')
        self.tree2.heading('#3', text='columna 3')
        self.tree2.heading('#4', text='columna 4')
        self.tree2.heading('#5', text='columna 5')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    app = App(window)

    window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno esta pregunta no debería contestarse, porque implica ir en contra de la filosofía del lenguaje python. Solo espero que sea usada con precaución.

El problema esta en que estas usando como gestor a grid y luego quieres que se adecue todo a un ancho y altura especifica.

Esto no se enseña en Python (Tkinter), y si en TCL/TK, porque es una mala practica, que no tiene mucha importancia en TCL/TK, pero la filosofía de python, es importante las buenas practicas de programación, por eso nadie usa el ancho y la altura específicos que se permite en TCL/TK, porque no es recomendable que los programadores, escojan libremente donde quieren poner las dimensiones y posición de cada widget. y en python solo enseñan buenas practicas de programacion, por que al ser python un lenguaje que corre en muchas maquinas, con diferentes resoluciones de pantalla, usar esta estrategia en contra de python, puede llevar a que el GUI, no funcione igual, en todas partes, algo que si pasa si se usa adecuadamente grid o pack.

Por eso, los que iniciamos conociendo TCL/TK, al tener malas practicas, terminamos casi siempre en aprendiendo Python(Tkinter), cuando sabes la posición y tamaño de cada widget, no usas grid ni, pack, sino que se usa el gestor place, con la ventaja, que puedes, ajustar luego el tamaño del widget, cuando llamas al parametro ancho o alto del place.

Por tanto lo que deberías hacer es reemplazar o renombrar la linea del gestor grid, y usar en su lugar place con el parametro ancho especifico de 1024 o la que tu quieras, pero esto solo será valido para el tamaño de pantalla exacto. y no es recomendable que se vuelva una costumbre, pues la aplicación puede correr en diferentes maquinas Windows Linux, Mac, con diferentes resoluciones, donde posiblemente la GUI quede por fuera.

renombrar la linea 19

```
self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)
```

y cambiarla por

```
self.tree.place(x=0,y=0,width=1024)
```

la linea 40

```
        self.tree2.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5)
```

, renombrarla o cambiarla por

```
self.tree2.place(x=0,y=300,width=1024)
```

Hay que tener cuidado con la posición en el eje y para que sea mayor a 200, para que no quede unido al widget superior.

Yo puse 300, pero puedes usar el que tu quieras, pues esto, lo hacia automáticamente el grid dependiendo de la pantalla.

Espero que te sirva y sigas en PYTHON y no te acostumbres a las malas practicas de TCL/TK.

Answer (score 0):

lo que podría hacer es captura el tamaño de la pantalla de tu ordenador y después pasarle esos datos al Treeview.

Capturamos el Ancho y Alto de la pantalla:

```py
user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
ancho, alto = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

Seguidos creamos el Treeview:

```py
grilla=ttk.Treeview(base,column=("columaFecha","columnaHabitacion","columnaCama","columnaTpLlamado"))
grilla.place(x=0,y=0,width=ancho,height=alto)
```